# How do I find the smallest epoch time that is in today (local timezone) with Perl?

Tags: perl, time, epoch

Perl time function is great, but how do I find the smallest epoch value that's in today? Since epoch is in seconds I would imagine that there are many epoch values that will correspond to a given day. How do I find the lowest in my timezone?

Comment: Use some form of the `localtime` function, and pass in midnight of the current day?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a supported use of the `timelocal`, but you should have no problem using it to get the information you want.

```
use Time::Local qw( timelocal );
my $epoch = timelocal(0,0,0, (localtime)[3,4,5]);
```

- I don't know of any time zone with a day with two midnights, so I can't test that.
- I tested with a time zone with a day with no midnight (2013-10-20 in America/Sao_Paulo), and it worked fine.

Comment: Leap seconds might matter if you need 100% to-the-second accuracy (they add them at midnight, so you get a time like "23:59:60". (I'm not sure how Perl and/or various operating systems account for leap seconds.)

Comment: @bigiain, As you showed, they are added *before* midnight, and thus don't affect the answer whatsoever.

Comment: my local Perl (5.10.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8) shows monotonically increasing epoch values across 20120630235958, 20120630235959, 20120701000000, and 20120701000001 - missing out the last leapsecond (which was at 20120630235960). If I ask it for the epoch at 00:00:00 on Sun 1 July 2012, it says 1341100800 - which I'm pretty sure was technically 23:59:60 on Sat 30 June 2012. (Maybe the OS and/or POSIX and/or my C libraries and/or Perl behaved differently at 20120630235960 though?)